# Autohotkey: How to determine which screen the taskbar is on?

Tags: autohotkey, taskbar

I want determine with Autohotkey which screen the taskbar is on?

If you want to know why, of course, tell ichs gladly.

Answer (score 0):

The Taskbar displays on your Primary Display Monitor, listed as Display 1. To find your primary Monitor in Autohotkey use [SysGet](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/SysGet.htm):

```
; Store the Monitor number of the Primary Monitor in OutPutVar
SysGet, OutPutVar, MonitorPrimary 
MsgBox % OutPutVar
```

There is known bug where when you have changed your Primary display the Taskbar might remain on your 2nd monitor while all your icons will be on your Primary. Read about [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2002029).

Comment: thanks, not helps. I have tried your tip, although it is actually already clear seemed to me that this is not the problem.  The window works (and that's always after reinstalling) "Debug" and his class SunAwtDialog. In the Autohotkey - test was "Debug" not found (does not seem to exist). If it should still exist but somehow, I would have it again in a visible region

Comment: Importend news: When I was just at the closing of redundant window I have a 2x2 pixels small window found. Its not named "Debug" (as was determined in an earlier test). The window is now called "Run". A miracle that I have discovered that small windows (not useful in my opinion). I have his sized it with WinMove,,,,,600,300 and everything was usefull. The window name "Debug" originates possibly still on the version 8. I'm not quite sure, anyway, it was then also read with AutoHotkey. Whey it was sized to 2x2? :-D Whey it happes often?